# float to unix epoch

Tags: php, floating-point, unix-timestamp

I am pulling data from an JSON database that is storing the time in unix epoch but for some reason the numbers are being floated when I'm pulling them out. This is something I've never had to deal with before. So basiclly a number like `1293083730000` is showing up as `1.293085408E+12` I need to get the number back to the epoch time so I can compare it to the current time. Any help would be great.

Comment: Strange. The code to retrieve the data?

Comment: Your time appears to be in milliseconds, the epoch time 1293083730 is for Thu Dec 23 00:55:30 2010

Comment: You're right, it's ms since the epoch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [engineering notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation), a convenient method of writing large numbers.  The number is still an integer.

The problem is is that PHP's internal types are too small to represent the number as a decimal, see the following example:

```
<?
$i = 1293083730000;
echo "\$i is $i\n\n";
echo sprintf("\$i is %d\n\n", $i);
echo sprintf("\$i is %e\n\n", $i);
?>
```

This outputs:

```
$i is 1293083730000

$i is 298573904

$i is 1.293084e+12
```

You need either a 64-bit platform or work with the number as a string or floating point value.  See the PHP documentation on Integers for more details:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Okay, how do I convert engineering notation to epoch? I'm bad with numbers. I've tried to use `floor()` and `round()` EDIT so i'm screwed?

Comment: I wouldn't mind working with the number as a string just not sure how to get a string out of my array. I know I sound dumb right now.

Comment: @BrandonRandon, divide by 1000 first then everything should work normally.

Comment: I deleted my answer: if you are running with a 32 bit OS, PHP unlike Java is not able to deal with 64-bits integers. Steve-o is correct - just divide your number by 1000, then you enter the 32-bits integer range, and you can treat it as an integer (since `time()` returns a value in seconds, not ms, you are ok to compare your new value with `time()` directly).

Comment: I was wondering what happend yo your post ring0 I was trying to give you a +1. If I go with `$arival_time = "1.293085408E+12";
echo $arival_time /1000;` i get `1293085408` which still isn't the correct time. Do i need to multiply that by something?

Comment: @BandonRandon No, you can use that number directly, and compare it with the return value of PHP `time()` function. Why isn't it the *correct time* ? it looks like an unix epoch time to me.

Comment: oh okay, But i need Ms not seconds since epoch. I should just be able to multipy that by 1000?

Comment: Just Kidding. Even though my time  is coming in ms since epoch This should work `$arival_time = "1.293085408E+12";
$time1 = ($arival_time /1000);
$time2= time() + (5*60);` then compare `$time1 to $time2` I feel silly now.

Answer (score 2):

In the `php.ini` configuration file, there is a value `'precision'`. 

It simply defines how many digits will be shown in a float number.

More informations in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision)

*You can increase the precision value and try again.*

Comment: shared host no control over php.ini...Boo